# Swift 4 protocol extension - convenience initializer default implementation

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out how to create a default protocol initializer  implementation in a protocol extension that implementing types can inherit.

It looks something like this:

```swift
protocol Initializable {
    associatedtype EntityType: ConcreteClass
    var container: Container<EntityType> { get set }
    init()
}

class Container<T: ConcreteClass> {
    typealias EntityType = T
    let configuration : Configuration

    init(config: Configuration) {
        configuration = config
    }

    func getAll() -> [EntityType] {
        return [EntityType()]
    }
}

extension Initializable {
    init(config: Configuration) {
        self.init()
        self.container = Container<EntityType>(config: config)
    }
}

final class Repo: Initializable {
    typealias EntityType = String
    var container: Container<String>
}
```

I end up with the following compiler error:

> Type 'Repo' does not conform to protocol 'Initializable'. Candidate
>   has non-matching type 'init(type: EntityType.Type)'

Comment: `EntityType()` how do you know `EntityType` has `init()` ?

Comment: Updated the question. 'EntityType' is of a ConcreteClass that has a `public init()`. The `Container` is actually initialized with another object.

Comment: There are distinct `EntityType` symbols in each class. In Container it doesn't have init() because it's just Codable, not derived from ConcreteClass.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update that type as well. Long story short: I want to provide a default initializer implementation in a protocol extension that is then implemented by other classes (they can specify the associated type and the container or even better, specify only the associated type and build the container based on the associated type.

Answer (score 1):

You use different init in protocol and extension.

```
init(type: EntityType)
```

You must implement realization of method init() in extension or in class

Comment: I've updated the question. It's more of a generic question but now it should fully match the existing code. The `Configuration` class is just another class.

Comment: @Cyupa Your error is because you add realization of init(config:) method, and call self.init() inside. But you don't add realization of init() method. You must add it realization to extension or class, or delete it and don't call from init(config:)